# DOM @keyframes move hide effects

Tags: dom, addeventlistener, move

This is going to be part of a module that I want to use in an educational example project, I tried to make Welcome go from left to right and up, every time I press the button, trying to control the movement with commands but it doesn't work.
Requirements:

- Only use javascript (forbidden to use jquery or others).
- Do not use location.reload () or window.history.go ().

Is there a solution or is it not possible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
    @keyframes move {
        0% {
            top: 250px; left: 0px;
        }
        50% {
            top: 250px; left: 300px;
        }
        100% {
            top: 20px; left: 300px;
        }
    }

    #mh1 {
        position: absolute;
        animation-name: move;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @keyframes hide {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        75% {
            opacity: 0;
            height: 100%;
            line-height: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0px;
            line-height: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    }

    #idesc {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    animation-name: hide;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    @keyframes show {
        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            height: 0px;
            line-height: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
    }
</style>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
    document.querySelector('#but').addEventListener('click', myfunc , false);
    function myfunc(event) {
        
        const element2 = document.querySelector('#idesc');
        element2.style.animationName = 'show';

        const element = document.querySelector('#int');
        element.style.animationPlayState = 'initial';
        element.innerHTML='<h1 id="mh1">Welcome!</h1>';
        
        setInterval(function(){
        const element2 = document.querySelector('#idesc');
        element2.style.animationName = 'hide';
        element2.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
        }, 3000);
        element2.style.animationName = "none";
        element.style.animationName = "none";
        element2.style.animationPlayState = 'initial';
  
     }

    });        

</script>   

</head>
<body>
<div id="idh">
    <button id="but">hello
    </button>
</div>    
<div id="idesc">
    <div id="int"></div>
    <div id="int2"></div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```